# Alamofire POST Bad Request

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

I'm trying to make a post request to my server through Alamofire but it returns a bad request saying that parameters are badly formed. Same requests is working in postman and swagger.

Here is the code:

```swift
var params = [
            "username": "jora@company.com",
            "password": "test123",
            "pushToken": "No token"
    ]

Alamofire.request("https://thankyouposta.com/api/auth", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: R.Api.headers).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            // ...
        case .failure(let error):
            // ...
        }
    }
```

**Update 1**

Parameters needs to be sent as form url encoded body

**Update 2**

Value of R.Api.headers is

```
["Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backend was an IIS server with redirection to Tomcat. I've excluded IIS and make the requests directly to Tomcat and it is working now. As I understood, the problem was in delivering the request from IIS to Tomcat.

**Solved**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send request as a form-urlencoded, you should put it as a headers and change your encoding:

```
let headers = [
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            ]
        var params = [
            "username": "jora@company.com",
            "password": "test123",
            "pushToken": "No token"
    ]

        Alamofire.request("your_url_here", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding:  URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON { response  in 
}
```

Comment: I forgot to specify in R.Api.headers are Content-Type with value application/x-www-form-urlencoded. I want to send this parameters as form url encoded

Comment: No, it is not solved, I can't send the request with form url encoded parameters.

Comment: The header I'm already using, the value of R.Api.headers is as your headers. With httpBody I've tried but is is the same error ((